# White space under nav bar, only goes away when border is added to header in next section

Tags: html, css

I have a white space under the navigation bar of my webpage. 
The only way I can get it to go away is to add a border to the header section below. 
I've double checked my code so many times, please help me identify where I am going wrong. 
I'm a beginner, so let me know if I'm totally off base with my structure.

In this snippet, you can see the result by simply un-commenting the on the header css.

I really want to learn what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks.

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.container {
 max-width: 940px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 10px;
} 


/******************************
   NAV
******************************/
nav {
 background-color: #393D44;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a:hover, .active {
 color: #4BAF70;
}


/******************************
   HEADER
******************************/
header {
 margin: 0;
 background-image: url("http://easylivingmom.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/grocery-store-lg.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 600px;
 /*border: 1px solid green;*/
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Grocery Shopping</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,700,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
   <nav>
    <div class= "container">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">What</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Where</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">When</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">How</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   

   <header>
    <div class= "container">
     <h1>Grocery Shopping</h1>
     <a href="#" class=btn>Get Involved</a>
    </div>
   </header>

   <section>
    <div class= "container">
    <!- Need to figure this section out ->
    </div>
   </section>

   <footer>
    <div class= "container">
     <p>&copy; Brianna Vay 2015</p>
     <p>Careers</p>
    </div>
   </footer>



  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You can get rid of that div in the nav section. It's not doing anything. Just put the class "container" right on the nav. You're probably getting padding/margin from that, just from a quick glance.

Comment: thanks @Araymer; i think i need to keep that div so my header bar spans past the 940px i've set all my containers to...

Comment: @BriannaVay check this out http://codepen.io/firnasfaris10/pen/JGKOZz

Comment: What you were seeing is a property of the CSS box model known as "collapsing margins", which you can read about at: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<h1>Grocery Shopping</h1>` inside the header have a `margin`. try removing the margin.

ie, `header .container > h1{ margin-top: 0}`

This will solve the white space

**PS**: add a class to the `h1` tag and target only this element

see this

```css
body {

  padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;

}

.container {

  max-width: 940px;

  margin: 0 auto;

  padding: 0 10px;

}

/******************************
       NAV
    ******************************/

nav {

  background-color: #393D44;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 10px 0;

}

nav ul li {

  list-style: none;

  display: inline-block;

}

nav ul li a {

  text-decoration: none;

  font-weight: 300;

  padding: 15px 10px;

  color: #fff;

}

nav ul li a:hover,

.active {

  color: #4BAF70;

}

/******************************
       HEADER
    ******************************/

header {

  margin: 0;

  background-image: url("http://easylivingmom.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/grocery-store-lg.jpg");

  background-size: cover;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  height: 600px;

  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Grocery Shopping</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,700,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">What</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Where</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">When</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">How</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 style="margin-top: 0">Grocery Shopping</h1>
        <a href="#" class=btn>Get Involved</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <!- Need to figure this section out ->
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <p>&copy; Brianna Vay 2015</p>
        <p>Careers</p>
      </div>
    </footer>



  </body>

  </html>
```